# flurry native ads integration

Tags: android, ads, flurry

I'm trying to integrate flurry native ads in my android app.

i did all as in guide described but receive error with 20 code

here is my code:

```
    FlurryAdNativeListener nativeListener = new FlurryAdNativeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFetched(FlurryAdNative flurryAdNative) {
            parseAssets(flurryAdNative);
        }

        @Override
        public void onShowFullscreen(FlurryAdNative adNative) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onShowFullscreen ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCloseFullscreen(FlurryAdNative adNative) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onCloseFullscreen " );
        }

        @Override
        public void onClicked(FlurryAdNative adNative) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onClicked " );
        }

        @Override
        public void onImpressionLogged(FlurryAdNative flurryAdNative) { }

        @Override
        public void onError(FlurryAdNative flurryAdNative, FlurryAdErrorType flurryAdErrorType, int errorCode) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onFetchFailed " + errorCode);
            tvAdStatus.setText("failed to fetch ad, error code " + errorCode + " , error type " + flurryAdErrorType.name());
        }

        @Override
        public void onAppExit(FlurryAdNative adNative) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onAppExit " );
        }
    };

 private void setupNativeAd() {
     nativeAd = new FlurryAdNative(this, "native ad in my feed list");
     nativeAd.setListener(nativeListener);
     nativeAd.setTrackingView(findViewById(R.id.llMain));
     nativeAd.fetchAd();

 }
```

log cat says:

```
E/FlurryAgent﹕ Ad server responded with the following error(s):
E/FlurryAgent﹕ Gemini error: Ad Computation Failed
I/FlurryAdsActivity﹕ onFetchFailed 20
E/FlurryAgent﹕ Ad server responded with the following error(s):
E/FlurryAgent﹕ Gemini error: Ad Computation Failed
```

That does this error message and code means? google says nothing...

Comment: This could happen if your ad space is not set up correctly or you did not initialize a Flurry session. Ensure that the ad space is set up for native ads and you are fetching from the exact same ad space (case-sensitive); also ensure that you initialized the Flurry session

Comment: Also, it isn't the best idea to set up a tracking view before the ad has been successfully fetched

Comment: i init session in app.onCreate via FlurryAgent.init
i copy code from ad space setup, it is active and placement set to Stream

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I had 500 thousand impressions a day before 8/18. Then the fill rate dropped to 0% in just one day.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem. My code was right. When I was testing it on an emulator, Gemini was always returning that error.

Testing the same exact code on a real device showed some ads.

It seems they are no serving ads for AVDs.

So, testing your code on a real Android device could probably solve your issue, orium